# Need HELP with topology - Subdivision

Tags: topology, subdivision-surface

I'm modeling knife handle. I'm using the "Subdivide modifier" on my mesh. Everybody is telling me don't use or make triangles. I did make a triangle but, somehow I changed it to the quad. Is this ok?

[image: Knife Handle]

But still doesn't look ok, funny diamond shape in the middle. If somebody can help draw lines on the image of how to do retopology.

I need later in modeling top edge(RED) to be sharper.
[image: Knife handle 2]
[image: kNIFE BACKDROP]

Comment: what do you mean by sharper? the top surface is completely flat... If you want to sharp the edges, bevel with ctrl B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could simply do that (following picture):

[image]

Comment: I edited my question, tnx for the response.

Comment: Tnx for help,... Bevel saves the day